# Issues with SMC after using caffeinate command

Tags: macbook-pro, command-line, crash

I've been using the caffeinate command regularly over the last few months and my Macbook Pro (mid 2012) has had SMC issues all of the sudden causing it to crash when I unplug the power cable.

I've reset the SMC a couple of times already and then things are fine for a couple of weeks, but then out of the blue I'll unplug my power cable and things crash.

Curious to know if there are any known issues with caffeinate, especially in older mac models. If so, anything I can do to prevent this issue?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to suspect the battery on an 8-year-old machine.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected caffeinate since the issues seem to coincide with when I started using the command regularly. I might replace the battery or a get a new machine eventually.

Comment: Maybe check it with [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) [freeware]

Comment: I did give it a try just now and my battery status just says fair with no battery failures reported.Though the design capacity is only at 65%. not great I suppose but not as bad as I would have expected.